# React JS fetch as POST to cross-origin, PHP returns 200 but without body response

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, fetch

I know similar questions have been asked, but nothing on here as worked. Thank you in advance!

I'm using fetch from a react JavaScript app (located at http://localhost:3000) to post data too, and get a response from a local PHP API (using XAMPP and located at http://local.api.mysite.com/user)

Every-time I get a 200 status without any returned headers or body. If I go to the PHP URL in my browser it works just fine

I've ensured cors is set in both js and php, set content types, turned off caching, and tried every suggested fix on here and Google.

This is a last resort

JS:

```js
fetch('http://local.api.mysite.com/user', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    }).then(console.log(response))
```

PHP:

```php
// Allow from any origin
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
}
// Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
    exit(0);
}
$output = json_encode(['status' => 'recieved']);
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($output));
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $output;
exit;
```

Previously I had limited my PHP headers to be more restrictive, but I found this code block and am using it to let anything pass for testing.

**Solution**
Rikin's comment on his answer had me open dev tools, go to the network tab, and view the response directly. This showed a server error that was occurring and leading to the empty response with a 200 status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `fetch` issue on how its built. You get a ***stream*** of response which you have to either parse it as `json` or `text` or `blob` and then look for actual response that we expect. I modified code a bit below to get you what you need.

```
fetch('http://local.api.mysite.com/user', {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
.then(data => data.ok && data.json())
.then(response => console.log(response));
```

This is what you get back in fetch response: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

Comment: Thanks for replying! I get "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" since the response is empty. If I swap the "data.json()" with just "data" then I get the response object with bodyUsed: false and empty body/headers and status: 200 statusText: "OK"

Comment: ok so with that atleast you are able to read the stream but now your response is empty so its more likely API issue returning no response with 200 status.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but if I go directly to the URL it does output a JSON response. I've verified spelling issues and even clicked on the response.url that is logged in console.log and it works directly

Comment: If it helps, if set the API to return 404 then the JS does pick that up

Comment: If you go to the URL direct then it becomes GET call so you are not testing same thing there. May be you can try to go to the url with dev console open and go to Network Tab, and then once call succeeds capture the fetch by right clicking on it and then Copy > Copy as fetch. Using that you will be able to compare that fetch v/s your code's fetch

Comment: I use a firefox extension to do POST requests in the browser but you got it with the Network Tab and viewing the response directly from there! There's an odd server error that occurs, but I can at least work with that. Thanks so much